# fatal: failed to load library `libcurl-4.dll`

Tags: git, dll, sh

I work in an IT department and today a user came with an unusual problem that we did not take care of, but I still want to help him.

You are trying to run a script on your computer but you get the following library error.
We have tried to download the specific library and copy it to the System32 path but the error continues.
Attached screenshoot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w4wt.png